# Using GeoIP2 database, I can find only in the USA

Tags: geoip, maxmind

I was asked to implement a new feature in one of our internal systems and for that, I was provided with MaxMind database file.

I created a console app with Visual Studio 2013 and .Net 4.5 and the NuGet package: MaxMind.Db.

I outputed the metadata information so you can know exactly what I am using :

```
Description:            GeoIP2 City database
Database type:          GeoIP2-City
Binary format version:  2.0
Build Date:             31-Mar-2015 4:58:01 PM
IP version:             6
```

When I search for 128.101.101.101, I get Minneapolis as expected.
But when I search for any of those :

```
10.107.148.199
10.120.0.131
10.99.128.13
192.168.4.144
```

I find nothing !!!

Could it be because the IP Version in Metadata is 6 ?  So I have the wrong file ?

Thanks for any help, regards, 
Claude VERNIER

Comment: The IP addresses you list are all private addresses. IP geolocation only works with public addresses.

Comment: @oschwald That looks like it qualifies as an answer. Was just about to add such an answer when I saw your comment, so by all means add it yourself first if you want the credit.

Comment: But of course !!!  Thank you for your answers...  I was testing with the DEV database where the IPs were from virtual machines....  how silly...    Using real data like 80.12.59.162 and 92.90.26.67, I get FRANCE but no City...  Would that be caused by the IP itself, my usage of the DB or the type of DB we bought ?  Thanks and regards.

Comment: Usually IP addresses are only accurate to nation level, USA is an exception presumably because the states are very large.